# 'Could not find project configuration' build error

Tags: visual-studio-2005, build, visual-c++

I'm getting the build error 'error VCBLD0007: Could not find project configuration RELEASE|X64 to build.' when attempting to build in that configuration. Release|Win32 works fine. The configuration definitely does exist in the project. I'm building with vcbuild in VS2005 and running on a x64 box.

Anyone have a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your error sounds like one I had a while ago. It turned out to be that we had forgotten to install the 64 bit options when we installed. One way to test was to rerun the installer and choose the change or remove and see if the 64 bit options are already installed or not.

Answer (score 1):

My advice in general in such a situation:

Remove the configuration concerned ("RELEASE|X64") permanently, save and quit visual studio. 
To do so, you must choose < Edit...> in the platform popup menu from the configuration manager.
Then restart and and re-create the configuration completely. It might be a good idea, to create some screen shots from the old config before removing it.

That might take some 30 minutes, but it probably will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: case sensitivity. Or it could be that the project/solution files are malformed. Check them out - they are simple text files. It would be best if you could provide them here, but I understand that it might not be possible.

Also, in case you don't know this (VS is not very intuitive about this), here's a quick explanation of how the configurations work:

There are two kinds of configurations - each project has its own set of configurations, and the solution has a set of configurations. Each project configuration describes how to build the specific project - compiler options, which files to include, etc. Each solution configuration however only describes which projects to build, and which project configuration to use for each specific project. Note, that there is no 1:1 mapping between project configurations and solution configurations. You can set them up any way you like.

The error seems to suggest that the solution configuration you are using references a project configuration that does not exist in that particular project.

Answer (score 0):

This error was occurring because the 64-bit tools for Visual Studio were not installed correctly. A reinstall fixed my issue.